# I'm trying to make a daily command but I keep getting the same error (Discord.py rewrite)

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to make a daily command (I'm well aware I haven't added the the actual daily part yet, just trying to get it to add the actual integer) I keep getting either user is missing or ctx is missing error.

Changing the order of user and ctx just result in the same error but gives user is a required argument if ctx is first and ctx is a required argument if user is put first.

```
@commands.command()
    async def dailydango(self, user, ctx):
        cur_dango = user['dango']
        await self.bot.pg_con.execute("UPDATE userse SET dango = $1 WHERE user_id = $2 and guild_id = $3", cur_dango + 200, user['user_id'], user['guild_id'])`
```

Here's the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 863, in invoke
>       await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
>     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 721, in invoke
>       await self.prepare(ctx)
>     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 685, in prepare
>       await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
>     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 599, in _parse_arguments
>       transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
>     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 445, in transform
>       raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
>   discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: ctx is a required argument that is missing.

Comment: What is `user` supposed to be?  How are you invoking this command?

Comment: User is like the "ctx.message.author" for the database, it pulls from the database to get their information. At what I understand from it's other uses.

Comment: How is the user expected to pass one of these objects from discord though?

Comment: The cog uses asyncpg which uses user as one of it's options for communicating with the database.

Comment: I don't think it does. The way you have this set up at the moment, `user` is intended to be a string that a person types into discord as part of calling the command. I think instead you want to use a converter to turn that into a `User` object, then use the attributes of that user object to look up `cur_dango` , probably in the database

Comment: If you want `user` to be the message author don't put it as an argument but use `user = ctx.author` instead